# Tridion DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationUrls causing StackOverflowException

Tags: web8, content-delivery

I am implementing a language switch in a .NET DD4T 2 website. In order to get the base URL for a website I am using the `DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationUrls(pubId)` method. But the implementation of this method invokes itself, at least in `Tridion.ContentDelivery, Version=8.1.0.1239`, leading to a `StackOverflowException`. This seems like a bug/untested Tridion code to me.

Anyone would know how to get the base URL of a website using the websites publication ID?

Comment: I don't have an 8.1 environment to test in. FWIW, this works in 8.5 (just tried a simple `foreach` loop on `dmr.GetPublicationUrls(5)` )

Comment: can you please add logs for this error ?

Comment: Thanks Nuno, upgrading to 8.5 indeed solved the issue, now I do get a list of base URLs as a result.